# Is there any method to check the JWT token cookie for different localhost ports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern

My E-comm web site has two different projects: admin and client. All users can login to their accounts on the client login page. How can I, as admin, redirect to an admin dashboard in the admin project securely? The client project runs on localhost:3000 and admin project runs on localhost:3001. How can I pass JWT cookies between two different ports and methods?

```
client login page
if (response.data) {  
          localStorage.setItem('token', response.data)
          window.location.href="http://localhost:3001/"
          
        }
//admin dashboard
  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    console.log('Token:', token);
    if (!token) {
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/login'; 
    }else{
      console.log("no set cookie")
    }

}, []);
```

When I run this code, it immediately begins to load the login page.

Comment: cookie's and localStorage are not meant to work across different domains for obvious reasons

Comment: Either have separate login pages, or if you want to have a shared login page (and don't want to deal with the hassle of cross-domain authentication) just serve both projects from the same domain under different paths. Use a reverse proxy for that if your two projects run as two separate applications.

Answer (score -1):

## You can use

```js
const a = window.open("http://localhost:3000")
console.log(a.localStorage)
```

to get the localstorage on other website/port and close it using `a.close()` so the popup won't show to the user

## or

create an invisible Iframe and use

```js
document.GetElementById("iframe").contentWindow.localStorage
```